# How to keep an urwid.Edit always in focus?

Tags: python, urwid

I have programmed with python+urwid a ircII-like screen, where I have a text flow the entire screen of the terminal, plus an editable text at the bottom as the prompt, to let the user insert commands and press enter.

The main body of the screen is an `urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker` and for each line of new text (e.g. command response) a new `urwid.Text` is created.

This code shows how I create the layout.

```
self._widgetPromptText = urwid.Edit(self._textPrompt, initial_text)
self._widgetLinesList = urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker([])
self._widgetBufferListBox = urwid.ListBox(self._widgetLinesList)

self._w = urwid.Frame(header=self._widgetHeader,
                         body=self._widgetBufferListBox,
                         footer=self._widgetPromptText,
                         focus_part="footer")
```

Ok, now the problem is that when my terminal window loses focus, and I click on it again, by clicking the title bar of the xterm window, OR by directly clicking the bottom `urwid.Edit` that acts as the user's input for commands, everything is fine.

BUT, if I click on the screen of the xterm window, the bottom `urwid.Edit` loses focus, so it also loses the cursor. I have to click again on the `urwid.Edit` to get the cursor appearing again, and be able to write.
It seems that when with the mouse I click the screen, urwid leave focus from the bottom `urwid.Edit` and gives it to the `urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker` or the `urwid.ListBox`, without the possibility of giving back focus to the `urwid.Edit`, unless I click with the mouse on it.

I *definitely* don't want this!
How I can tell urwid to not give focus to the `urwid.SimpleFocusListWalker` or the `urwid.ListBox`, or simply to give focus to the `urwid.Edit` when one of them gets it?

More importantly, I wish to be possible to tell urwid to *never* leave focus from the `urwid.Edit` I use to write commands.

Any help?!

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, it seems I have been able to solve the error by adding this code to my class:

```
def mouse_event(self, size, event, button, col, row, focus):
    pass
```

Now, when I click on the surface of the terminal, the cursor doesn't disappear anymore.
That's exactly what I was looking for.